# May i know in Linux kernel what is the purpose of GFP_HARDWALL flag?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

GFP flags are used for memory allocation. What is the purpose of GFP_HARDWALL flag in Linux kernel?

Comment: Does that symbol exist? Or are you referring to `__GFP_HARDWALL`?

Answer (score 6):

It restricts allocation to the current cpuset, where a cpuset is a (guess!) set of CPUs and memory nodes.

Basically, your user process may be confined in a cpuset consisting of CPU#1 and CPU#2 but not CPU#3 nor CPU#4. Maybe there is some memory MEM#1 which is local to CPUs #1 and #2 but not the others, so this memory is part of the cpuset. Maybe there is some other memory MEM#2 local to CPUs #3 and #4, so this one is not part of the cpuset.

__GFP_HARDWALL ensures that you cannot allocate from MEM#2.

Comment: This example makes it very easy to understand!

Answer (score 3):

I can't for sure tell. You are probably referring to `__GFP_HARDWALL` which is an internal symbol which you are not really supposed to look at. Nevertheless, here are my findings.

From [include/linux/gfp.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/gfp.h):

Comment on `#define __GFP_HARDWALL`:

> /* Enforce hardwall cpuset memory allocs */

Not that I really understand what hardwall means in that sentence, but you might. `__GFP_HARDWALL` is used in the definitions of `GFP_USER`, `GFP_HIGHUSER` and `GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE` as well as `GFP_CONSTRAINT_MASK`. From the first three, I'm guessing it has something to do with user-space.

From [kernel/cpuset.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/cpuset.c):

Comments on the `__cpuset_node_allowed_softwall` function (partly omitted):

> ```
> * cpuset_node_allowed_softwall - Can we allocate on a memory node?
> * ...
> * If we're in interrupt, yes, we can always allocate. If __GFP_THISNODE is
> * set, yes, we can always allocate. If node is in our task's mems_allowed,
> * yes. If it's not a __GFP_HARDWALL request and this node is in the nearest
> * hardwalled cpuset ancestor to this task's cpuset, yes. If the task has been
> * OOM killed and has access to memory reserves as specified by the TIF_MEMDIE
> * flag, yes.
> * Otherwise, no.
> *
> * If __GFP_HARDWALL is set, cpuset_node_allowed_softwall() reduces to
> * cpuset_node_allowed_hardwall(). Otherwise, cpuset_node_allowed_softwall()
> * might sleep, and might allow a node from an enclosing cpuset.
> *
> * cpuset_node_allowed_hardwall() only handles the simpler case of hardwall
> * cpusets, and never sleeps.
> *
> * <OMITTED>
> *
> * GFP_USER allocations are marked with the __GFP_HARDWALL bit,
> * and do not allow allocations outside the current tasks cpuset
> * unless the task has been OOM killed as is marked TIF_MEMDIE.
> * GFP_KERNEL allocations are not so marked, so can escape to the
> * nearest enclosing hardwalled ancestor cpuset.
> *
> * Scanning up parent cpusets requires callback_mutex. The
> * __alloc_pages() routine only calls here with __GFP_HARDWALL bit
> * _not_ set if it's a GFP_KERNEL allocation, and all nodes in the
> * current tasks mems_allowed came up empty on the first pass over
> * the zonelist. So only GFP_KERNEL allocations, if all nodes in the
> * cpuset are short of memory, might require taking the callback_mutex
> * mutex.
> *
> * The first call here from mm/page_alloc:get_page_from_freelist()
> * has __GFP_HARDWALL set in gfp_mask, enforcing hardwall cpusets,
> * so no allocation on a node outside the cpuset is allowed (unless
> * in interrupt, of course).
> *
> * <OMITTED>
> *
> * Rule:
> * Don't call cpuset_node_allowed_softwall if you can't sleep, unless you
> * pass in the __GFP_HARDWALL flag set in gfp_flag, which disables
> * the code that might scan up ancestor cpusets and sleep.
> ```

In the same file, there are also references to hardwall cpuset and hardwall memory. Still not sure what exactly hardwall means, but let's follow it to cpuset.

(There's a lot of mentions to hardwall in the *tile* architecture, but since that's the only one, I believe it's not related to what we are talking about here).

I hit the jackpot. The [documentation on cpusets](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/cgroups/cpusets.txt) says:

> ### 1.4 What are exclusive cpusets ?
>
> If a cpuset is cpu or mem exclusive, no other cpuset, other than
>   a direct ancestor or descendant, may share any of the same CPUs or
>   Memory Nodes.
>
> A cpuset that is cpuset.mem_exclusive *or* cpuset.mem_hardwall is "hardwalled",
>   i.e. it restricts kernel allocations for page, buffer and other data
>   commonly shared by the kernel across multiple users. All cpusets,
>   whether hardwalled or not, restrict allocations of memory for user
>   space. This enables configuring a system so that several independent
>   jobs can share common kernel data, such as file system pages, while
>   isolating each job's user allocation in its own cpuset. To do this,
>   construct a large mem_exclusive cpuset to hold all the jobs, and
>   construct child, non-mem_exclusive cpusets for each individual job.
>   Only a small amount of typical kernel memory, such as requests from
>   interrupt handlers, is allowed to be taken outside even a
>   mem_exclusive cpuset.

I'm going to leave you with this because any conclusion I make might in fact turn out wrong. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable in this particular field would come around and enlighten us.